# Fastest/shortest way to build unique tree in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tree, query-optimization

What is the fastest/shortest/one-liner (not possible :p) way to build a unique tree of elements from a tree where many of the elements are duplicated/missing in some nodes, given the tree has a defined set of nodes (which we'd use this algorithm to figure out so we don't have to manually do it).

It could be XML/JSON(hash), or whatever.  So something like this:

```
root {
    nodes {
        nodeA {}
        nodeB {
            subNodeA {}
        }
    }
    nodes {
        nodeA {
            subNodeA {}
        }
        nodeB {
            subNodeX {}
        }
    }
}
```

...converted to this:

```
root {
    nodes {
        nodeA {
            subNodeA {}
        }
        nodeB {
            subNodeA {}
            subNodeX {}
        }
    }
}
```

Same with xml:

```
<root>
    <nodes>
        <nodeA/>
        <nodeB>
            <subNodeA/>
        </nodeB>
    </nodes>
    <nodes>
        <nodeA>
            <subNodeA/>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeB>
            <subNodeX/>
        </nodeB>
    </nodes>
</root>
```

```
<root>
    <nodes>
        <nodeA>
            <subNodeA/>
        </nodeA>
        <nodeB>
            <subNodeA/>
            <subNodeX/>
        </nodeB>
    </nodes>
</root>
```

The xml/json files could be decently large (1MB+), so having to iterate over every element depth-first or something seems like it would take a while.  It could also be as small as the example above.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what all the unique paths are, so even just getting the paths into an array of strings would be perfect, I could create a tree from that.

Comment: I don't think you can even represent that structure with JSON; you have two keys named "nodes".

Comment: lol, true, i just wrote that up real quick.  I guess it boils down to, how do I find all the unique values in a tree, maybe the leaf nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll get you a set of unique paths:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'set'

xml = Nokogirl::XML.parse(your_data)
paths = Set.new
xml.traverse {|node| next if node.text?; paths << node.path.gsub(/\[\d+\]/,"").sub(/\/$/,"")}
```

Does that get you started?

[response to question in comment]

Adding attibute-paths is also easy, but let's go at least a little bit multi-line:

```
xml.traverse do |node|
  next if node.text?
  paths << (npath = node.path.gsub(/\[\d+\]/,"").sub(/\/$/,""))
  paths += node.attributes.map {|k,v| "#{npath}@#{k}"}
end
```

Comment: Good answer, I love Set. Not used enough.

Comment: no way, hard-frickin-core.  that's it, I can't believe it, one line! thanks so much glenn.  how would you add to it to include unique paths to all the attributes :)?  /root/nodes/nodeA/@customAttribute.